# Интеграция QAbstractTableModel и cv::Mat

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, opencv, шаблоны-с++

Потребовалось решить задачу вывода в виджете таблицы содержимого объекта класса матрицы `cv::Mat`. Но класс матрицы - шаблонный (точнее сказать не он сам, у него лишь методы шаблонные, а его наследники, но это сути не меняет). В качестве типов значений данных у объекта может быть и `char`, и `int`, и `float`, и прочие из состава предопределённых в соответствующем перечислении (`enum`) фреймворка OpenCV.

Проблема заключается в том, что класс `QAbstractTableModel` шаблонным не является, но его методы `data()` и `setData()` должны каким-то образом при "общении" с `cv::Mat` тип данных всё же передавать.

Для наглядности, решение при помощи обычного `switch`, где `_private` - шаблонная обёртка над `cv::Mat`:

```
//! Чтение данных из модели.
QVariant MatrixModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if(_private && index.isValid()) {
        switch(role) {
            case Qt::DisplayRole: {
                const int chns = _private->chns();
                if(chns == 1) return data(index.row(), index.column(), 0);

                QStringList values;
                for(int chn = 0; chn < chns; ++chn)
                    values << data(index.row(), index.column(), chn).toString();

                return values.join(QLatin1Char(':'));

            } break;

            ...

            default: break;
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}

//! Внесение данных в модель.
bool MatrixModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value
    , int role) {

    if(_private && index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
        bool ok = false;

        //! Символ двоеточия служит для разделения значений на разных цветовых каналах матрицы.    
        QStringList values
            = value.toString().split(QLatin1Char(':'), QString::SkipEmptyParts);

        if(!values.isEmpty()) {
            for(int i = 0, n = values.size(); i < n; ++i) {
                ok = setData(index.row(), index.column(), i, values.at(i));
                if(!ok) break;
            }
        }

        if(ok) {
            emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>(1,role));

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//! Чтение данных из матрицы.
QVariant MatrixModel::data(int row, int col, int chn) const {
    switch(_private->depth()) {
        case CV_8U:  return _private->data<uchar>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_8S:  return _private->data<char>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_16U: return _private->data<ushort>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_16S: return _private->data<short>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_32S: return _private->data<int>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_32F: return _private->data<float>(row,col,chn);
        case CV_64F: return _private->data<double>(row,col,chn);
    }

    return QVariant();
}

//! Внесение данных в матрицу.
bool MatrixModel::setData(int row, int col, int chn, const QVariant &value) {
    bool ok = false;

    switch(_private->depth()) {
        case CV_8U: {
            int val = value.toInt(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<uchar>(row, col, chn, (uchar)val);
        } break;

        case CV_8S: {
            int val = value.toInt(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<char>(row, col, chn, (char)val);
        } break;

        case CV_16U: {
            int val = value.toInt(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<ushort>(row, col, chn, (ushort)val);
        } break;

        case CV_16S: {
            int val = value.toInt(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<short>(row, col, chn, (short)val);
        } break;

        case CV_32S: {
            int val = value.toInt(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<int>(row, col, chn, val);
        } break;

        case CV_32F: {
            float val = value.toFloat(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<float>(row, col, chn, val);
        } break;

        case CV_64F: {
            float val = value.toDouble(&ok);
            if(ok) _private->setData<double>(row, col, chn, val);
        } break;
    }

    return ok;
}
```

Как хорошо заметно, код разрастается непомерно, хотя по своей сути совершенно однотипен. Как возможно эффективнее с точки зрения компактности организовать это хозяйство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, не нравятся нагромождения из `switch`. Я бы предложил сделать следующее:
Завести в классе `std::map`(можно QMap, не суть):

```
std::map<int, std::function<bool()>> _callbacks;
```

где вместо `int` впишите тип того перечисления, которое Вы используете в `switch` - я его не знаю.
Затем заведите общую функцию:

```
template <typename T>
bool setData(int row, int col, int chn, const QVariant &value)
{
    if(value.canConvert<T>())
    {
        _private->setData<T>(row, col, chn, value.value<T>());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Теперь зарегистрируем соответствие наших глубин и функций для них(где-нибудь в конструкторе):

```
_callbacks[CV_8U] = &setData<uchar>;
_callbacks[CV_8S] = &setData<char>;
...
```

Теперь перепишем нашу `setData`:

```
bool MatrixModel::setData(int row, int col, int chn, const QVariant &value) {
    return _callbacks[_private->depth()](row, col, chn, value);
}
```

Для `data()` можно сделать аналогично.

Comment: Да, это безусловно лучше, чем "switch", спасибо. Единственное, сейчас подумал, что строка "int val = value.toInt(&ok);" немного не вписывается, т.к. в зависимости от "Т" там может быть и "value.toFloat()", и "value.toDouble()". Но это похоже решаемо через вызов "QVariant::convertTo()", которая тоже шаблонная.

Comment: Исправил ответ.